# Should I add .egg-info, build and dist directories to .gitignore

Tags: git, github, package

I am completely new to package development.

When I run `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel` command, it is creating 3 additional folders in my package directory:

1. build
2. dist
3. package_name.egg-info

Should I add them to .gitignore or should I just delete them completely?

I am not even sure I am asking the right question. Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%5Bpython%5D+build+dist+egg-info+ignore

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to add them to the `.gitignore` file.